# Classical Nullstellensatz implies Hilbert Nullstellensatz

Tags: algebraic-geometry, solution-verification, ring-theory

In artin's Algebra book (1st edition) the following theorems are stated:

(Hilbert's Nullstellensatz) In $\mathbb{C}[x_1,...,x_n]$ maximal ideals are of the form $\langle x_1-a_1,...,x_n-a_n\rangle$.

(Classical Nullstellensatz) $f_1,...,f_n\in \mathbb{C}[x_1,...,x_n] $. If $g=0$ in the variety defined by zeros of $f_1,...,f_n$, then there is a power $g^m\in \langle f_1,...,f_n\rangle$

He then asks us to prove that the Hilbert Nullstellensatz is a consequence of the Classical Nullstellensatz.

---

I think I was able to prove this, but it is not exactly pretty, I am looking for nicer solutions and for any possible flaw in my argument. Take $\mathcal{M}$ a maximal ideal and suppose $\mathcal{M}\not= \langle x_1-a_1,...,x_n-a_n\rangle$ for any $(a_1,...,a_n)\in \mathbb{C}^n$. Because $\mathcal{M}$ is maximal and $\langle x_1-a_1,...,x_n-a_n\rangle$ are proper ideals of our ring this means that:

$$\mathcal{M}\subset \langle x_1-a_1,...,x_n-a_n\rangle \quad \text{cannot hold.} $$

In other words, for every $(a_1,...,a_n)\in \mathbb{C}^n$ there is $m_{(a_1,...,a_n)}\in \mathcal{M}$ but not in $ \langle x_1-a_1,...,x_n-a_n\rangle $. This means that $m_{(a_1,...,a_n)}(a_1,...,a_n)\not=0$. Similarly, because $\langle x-a_1,...,x-a_n\rangle$ are maximal ideals, if it were contained in $\mathcal{M}$ it would be $\mathcal{M}$, so we also need $m^{(a_1,...,a_n)}\in \langle x-a_1,...x-a_n\rangle$ but not in $ \mathcal{M}$.

Consider the following variety where $f_1,...,f_k$ are drawn from $\mathcal{M}$, which has $d\geq 1$ zeros given by $k_1,...,k_d\in \mathbb{C^n}$.

$$\begin{cases}
f_1=0\\
....\\
f_k=0\end{cases}$$

$m^{k_1}\cdot...\cdot m^{k_d}$ is zero in the variety, so $(m^{k_1}\cdot...\cdot m^{k_d})^n\in \langle f_1,...,f_k\rangle\subset \mathcal{M}$ by the Nullstellensatz. Because $\mathcal{M}$ is maximal it is prime which implies that $m^{k_1}\cdot...\cdot m^{k_d}\in \mathcal{M}$ and $m^{k_j}\in \mathcal{M}$ for some $j$ which is absurd!

Hence a variety drawn from $k$ polynomials of $\mathcal{M}$ has no zeros. But this implies by a proposition from Artin:

$$g_1f_1+...+g_k f_k=1\in \mathcal{M}$$

So $\mathcal{M}=\mathbb{C}[x_1,...,x_n]$ which is absurd.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First we record a corollary of the classical theorem. (The proof is behind the spoiler block, in case you want to prove it yourself.)

**Corollary:** If $I, J \subset \mathbb{C}[x_1, \dots, x_n]$ are ideals where $Z(I) = Z(J)$ as subsets of $\mathbb{C}^n$, then $\sqrt{I} = \sqrt{J}$.

> *Proof.* Let $f \in \sqrt{I}$. Then, for some $n$, $f^n$ vanishes along $Z(I) = Z(J)$, so for some $m$, $(f^n)^m \in J$ by the theorem, so $f \in \sqrt{J}$. Hence, $\sqrt{I} \subseteq \sqrt{J}$ and we conclude by symmetry.

Now, if $\mathcal{M} \subset \mathbb{C}[x_1, \dots, x_n]$ is a maximal ideal. Then $Z(\mathcal{M}) \subset \mathbb{C}^n$ is nonempty by the corollary, so we can find some $(a_1, \dots, a_n) \in Z(\mathcal{M})$. It then follows that $\mathcal{M} \subseteq (x_1 - a_1, \dots, x_n - a_n)$, which implies the desired result.

EDIT: Let $I \subset \mathbb{C}[x_1, \dots, x_n]$ be an ideal. Then we define the *zero locus of $I$* to be $$Z(I) = \{a \in \mathbb{C}^n \;|\; f(a) = 0\text{ for all }f\text{ in } I\}$$ and the *radical of $I$* to be $$\sqrt{I} = \{f \in \mathbb{C}[x_1, \dots, x_n]\;|\; f^n \in I \text{ for some } n \geq 0\}.$$

Comment: Could you explain please explain the definition of $Z(I)$ and $\sqrt{I}$? I am sure it is standard notation, but I have never seen it.

Comment: @Kadmos Sure, sorry about that. I didn't learn from this book so I didn't realize Artin hadn't introduced these yet. I'll add these definitions in an edit shortly.

Comment: Thank you for the edit. I understand the corollary as an application of the classical Nullstellensatz. It is still not exactly clear to me why $Z(\mathcal{M})$ in non empty though. Sorry.

Comment: The point is if $Z(\mathcal{M}) = \emptyset$, then $Z(\mathcal{M}) = Z((1))$, where $(1)$ denotes the unit ideal. It then follows that $\mathcal{M} = \sqrt{\mathcal{M}} = \sqrt{(1)} = (1)$. This first equality uses that $\mathcal{M}$ is a prime ideal, the second equality is the corollary, and the last equality is because $I \subset \sqrt{I}$ for any ideal.

Comment: Completely clear now. Such a clever argument. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

$(1)$ Any $\mathfrak{m}_a:=\langle x_1-a_1,\cdots,x_n-a_n\rangle$ is indeed maximal, as $\Bbb C[x_\bullet]/\mathfrak{m}_a\cong\Bbb C$ is a field as witnessed by the "evaluate at $a$" map $\Bbb C[x_\bullet]\to\Bbb C$.

$(2)$ The nullstellensatz establishes a Galois connection given by $J\sim Z(J)$ and $X\sim V(X)$ between *nonempty* zero sets (of proper ideals) and radical ideals. Maximal ideals are surely radical, and maximality is equivalent to not being strictly *contained in* any greater radical ideal, which by this connection (which reverses inclusions) translates to the statement: $Z(\mathfrak{m})$ *does not contain* any strictly smaller zero set. This tells you $Z(\mathfrak{m})$ is a point $a$ and taking the inverse of the connection you see $\mathfrak{m}=V(\{a\})=\langle x_1-a_1,\cdots,x_n-a_n\rangle$.